# sudo apt-get update message

Tags: command-line, sudo

When I'm doing the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

how can i fix this? what does this means?

Thanks !

Comment: See: [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

Answer (score 2):

The PPA `ppa:chris-lea/node.js` doesn't contains Vivid packages. Therefore remove the PPA via
the command below to prevent downgrading or uninstalling existing packages

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

Execute

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

to remove the PPA without leaving anything behind.

Comment: Didnt worked this message appears>  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~chris-lea: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'

Comment: Which message do you mean?

Comment: raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~chris-lea: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'

Comment: Try it again later. The error says, it's a temporary failure in the name resolution. In other words, a network problem.